# How do I allow automatic page breaks within a listing?

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, page-breaking

I have some code inside `tcolorbox` environments defined by `lstlistings`, and I want to be able to have a listing automatically page break to avoid so much vertical space at the bottom after a listing. I've tried working with `\raggedbottom` and `\flushbottom`, but neither are good options. How can I tell my `tcolorbox` to automatically break the page and continue the listing on the next page?

Comment: What happens if you put `breakable=true` as an optional argument to `\tcolorbox`?

Comment: @Landak that fixes it--thanks!